# C++ operator overloading error: no match for 'operator>>' in 'is >> "("'

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to learn operator overloading and I got an error on my first attempt.

```
template<typename T>
class Pair
{
public:
    T x; T y;
    Pair(T x, T y): x(x), y(y){};
    ~Pair(){};

    /* data */
};
template<typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const Pair<T> &p)
{
    return os<<"("<<p.x<<", "<<p.y<<")";
}

template<typename T>
istream& operator>>(istream &is, Pair<T> &p)
{
    return is>>"(">>p.x>>", ">>p.y>>")";
}
```

I want to be able to do the following:

```
Pair<int> p;
cin>>p;
cout<<p;
```

And giving input for `Pair` object means being able to give `(1, 2)` as input which after `cin`, produces a `Pair<int>`.

I get a compile time error at `is>>"("`. What is the way to correct this?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I don't think it matters. They are trying to insert into a string literal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you're trying to read into literals in the extractor. I'd suggest fixing this by reading a `char` first and comparing it with `'('`. You signal an error if that fails, otherwise extract `T` and repeat the process.

In code:

```
template <typename T>
istream& operator>> (istream &is, Pair<T> &p)
{
  char c;
  if (!(is >> c)) return is;
  if (c != '(') {
    is.setstate(is.failbit);
    return is;
  }
  if (!(is >> p.x >> c)) return is;
  if (c != ',') {
    is.setstate(is.failbit);
    return is;
  }
  if (!(is >> p.x >> c)) return is;
  if (c != ')') {
    is.setstate(is.failbit);
  }
  return is;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
return is>>"(">>p.x>>", ">>p.y>>")";
```

is nonsense: you are trying to move the information of the stream 'is' into the constant string ")".  I think what you want is this:

```
template<typename T>
istream& operator>>(istream &is, Pair<T> &p)
{
   is.seekg(1, std::ios::cur); // skip 1 char, "("
   is >> p.x;
   is.seekg(2, std::ios::cur); // skip 2 chars, ", "
   is >> p.y;
   is.seekg(1, std::ios::cur); // skip 1 char, ")"
}
```

Comment: Your edit was after my answer, and that requirement is not in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to read into string literals `"("` and `")"`. You cannot do that.

Try this:

```
template<typename T>
istream& operator>>(istream &is, Pair<T> &p)
{
    return is >> p.x>> p.y;
}
```

Comment: then I have to give input as "1 2" while I want to be able to read "(1, 2)" into a Pair<int> object

Comment: @prongs well, that is a different issue, which you did not specify in your question. You need to parse the input string first.

Comment: @juanchopanza On the other hand, the inserter writes the parentheses and comma. It would be weird for the extractor to fail on such input.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to read "(" string literal in input operator overloading just read p.x and py.